# Observer: Implement with pattern (subject & observer) or inter-thread communication (wait & notify)

Tags: java

I usually use the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) *pattern*, my colleague at work though has implemented an Observer using Thread intercommunication (using `wait` and `notify`/`notifyAll`).

**Should I implement my observers using the pattern or inter-Thread-communication using wait and notify? Are there any good reasons to avoid one approach and always use the other?**

I've always gone with the first one, using the pattern, out of convention, and because it seems more expressive (involved identifiers are a good way to express and understand what is communicated and how).

EDIT:

I'm using the pattern in a Swing GUI, he's using the inter-thread solution in an Android application.

In his solution one thread generates data and  then calls `notify`, to wake up another thread that paints the generated data and calls `wait` after every paint.

His argument for the `wait`/`notify` solution is that it creates less threads and even several concurrent calls to `notify` will cause only 1 paint event, whereas an observer-based solution would call a repaint with every call. He says it's just another valid approach, but doesn't claim he's done it for performance reasons.

My argument is that I would express the communication among objects on the OO design level rather than use a language-specific feature that makes the communication almost invisible. Also, low-level thread communication is hard to master, might be hard to understand by other readers, and should rather be implemented on a higher level, i. e. using a `CyclicBarrier`. I don't have any sound arguments for one or the other solution, but I was wondering if there are any sound arguments for either one or the other approach (i. e. *"This-and-that can happen, if you use this approach, whereas in the other one that's not possible."*).

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to approach this pattern, but you need to provide more info to accurately determine an optimal execution strategy. Specifically, what you are trying to accomplish is key. Is this a thick client application? A web application? Are you using JMS, etc. The answers will likely vary based on your input.

Comment: I've added some information to my original post (was too long to be posted as a comment).

Comment: The multiple calls to repaint can perhaps be avoided by using the `setChanged` flag; that's what it's for. Alternatively, your `update` methods can help here, by looking at what messages they receive from the Observables. Either of these are probably easier to debug than thread synchronization.

Comment: Sounds like his solution would be done easily with a BlockingQueue and skipping the low level threading stuff altogether.  It's a valid approach if you are in a threaded environment and only want one consumer to multiple producers.  This is a specific use case for observer/observable though.  I am not sure what is being gained in the wait/notify case listed if only one thread is producing and one is consuming and the consumer blocks the producer.

Comment: He *does* have several producers, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  The wait/notify mechanism is used for thread synchronization, and while your colleague may have used it within an Observer/Observable implementation, it is not, in itself the pattern implementation.  It simply means it is a multithreaded implementation.

There are many implementations of this pattern, and they are typically tailored to the environment in which you are working.  There are event mechanisms built into most UI frameworks/toolkits.  JMS for distributed environments, ...

I don't find much use for the generic Observer/Observable classes provided by the JDK, and from experience I haven't found many other developers use them either.  Most will use a provided mechanism, if appropriate, or roll their own specific and ultimately more useful implementation if needed.

Since I have done most of my coding in an OSGi environment of late, I have a preference for a variation of observer/observable called the [whiteboard pattern](http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/whiteboard.pdf).  This may or may not be feasible for you, depending on your environment.

Comment: I'm am aware they're different, I just wonder if one's to be favored over the other - I'd go with the pattern, but don't have a good point, why. And thanks for pointing me to the whiteboard pattern!

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid, or rather refrain from, inter-thread communication in 99.99% of the cases. If there is a real need for a multi threaded solution, you should use a higher level concurrency mechanism such as an ExecutorService or a good concurrency library such as jetlang: http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/.

Comment: And I'm looking for sound arguments to explain *why* I should avoid it, and why it isn't good for his specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult.  I would normally use Observer / Observable when not explicitly writing a multithreaded application.  However, convention in this case might be for you to use his design.  Perhaps see if you can abstract it out somehow so that you can replace it with the Observer pattern at a later stage if necessary?

However, I found these two articles which seem to indicate that the Observer/Observable pattern in Java is not ideal and should be avoided.

[An inside view of Observer](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2003/jw-0328-designpatterns.html) and
[The event generator idiom](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-09-1998/jw-09-techniques.html)

Comment: Didn't exactly answer my question, but interesting articles, thanks.